# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 in Mongodb Compass

Tags: mongodb, econnrefused

I restarted my computer to try to update it, and before restarting, I was also working on another project. Now, my project with a node.js backend is giving me this error:

```
reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
            at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1132:16) {
          name: 'MongoNetworkError'
        },
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 58154302,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: []
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
```

and my mongodb compass is giving me: `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`. My operating system is macOS Big Sur.

In another post someone suggested restarting the `mongod` process and connecting again. I tried following those instructions [mac-mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb-community-edition), but when I go to 'From a new terminal, issue the following: `mongosh`' my terminal gave me `command not found: mongosh`. I also tried testing it with `PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.4/bin" mongo MongoDB shell version v4.4.13` and I still got `Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017,` with connection refused.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

Comment: Please confirm mongod is running. Restarting alone won't help if it fails to restart. If there is no mongod running, start it manually from the terminal `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` and see what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting mongodb helped me:

```
brew services stop mongodb-community@5.0
```

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete socket file

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Restart mongodb service

```
sudo service mongod restart
mongosh
```

Comment: Hei I had the same problem in arch but solved now using your solution

Answer (score 0):

It may be happened due to the mongoDB server stopped. To resolve this, go to task manager. In the top bar, click Services. Search mongoDB in the set up files. If the status is "Stopped". Give a right click and start running the server. It will work again. For confirming this action, open the cmd and type `mongosh` and youll be getting the connection result.